# Smaller window size causing cut off content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to design a new website for myself but coming across some big problems when trying to make it compatible with smaller devices.

When running the website at larger resolutions and everything looks fine, until you start to drop it down to mobile and some tablet sizes. When the window becomes smaller, I lose content at the bottom of my website, the scroll bar does not go any further. I can kind of fix this but then I get a horrific horizontal scroll bar that is filled with no content.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ZzF.png

I have tried using all the overflow methods but still cannot find a fix.

Link to website so you can view for yourself: [Website](http://testing.lewistravis.co.uk/)

Comment: You need to get deeper in the topic of #responsive design with CSS. What you intend to do is pretty easy, once you study responsive CSS.

Comment: On style.css you have assign a 960px width to main class.you have to make it auto for tablet view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow-x` should fix your issue.

```
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```